# Salesforce and RETS MLS Data feed Integration

Tags: integration

How to integrate the RETS MLS Data Feed and Salesforce.

I don't have any RETS API but i need to integrate to RETS and get data from RETS and display it in my visualforce page.

Can any one help me how to achieve this integration process.

Thanks In Advance,